# Getting an alpha channel when using CIFilters [How to clear it]

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimage, core-graphics, core-image, cifilter

I have a bit of an issue with applying a sharpening filter on a UIImage.

The code works perfectly but the problem that the resulting UIImage has an Alpha channel. This in turn causes some performance issues.

This is how I initialise my context and filter

```
EAGLContext *myEAGLContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
 NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[options setObject: [NSNull null] forKey: kCIContextWorkingColorSpace];
context = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:myEAGLContext options:options];
sharpenLuminanceFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISharpenLuminance"];
```

And I use the following function to generate an image

```
- (UIImage *)applySharpingFilter:(UIImage *)originalImage withValue:(float)value{

CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:originalImage.CGImage];
[sharpenLuminanceFilter setValue:image forKey:@"inputImage"];
[sharpenLuminanceFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:value] forKey:@"inputSharpness"];
CIImage * result = sharpenLuminanceFilter.outputImage;
CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[result extent]];
 double scaleFactor = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg scale:scaleFactor orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
[sharpenLuminanceFilter setValue:nil forKey:@"inputImage"];
return finalImage;
```

}

Is there anyway I can specify that I want the resulting Image to be OPAQUE and have no alpha channel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`CIColorMatrix`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) filter. Set the matrix to identity and the bias to [0, 0, 0, 1], and it should add 1 to the alpha, which will cause it to be solid.

I'd be curious to know in which way an alpha channel is affecting your performance.

Comment: That just made the entire picture more white and didnt eliminate the alpha channel. That issue affects the performance when you are scrolling it is slowly if you have images with transparency

Comment: Is your channel order something other than RGBA? If so, you may need to change the bias vector so that the 1 is in the same position as your alpha channel.

Comment: I tried all combinations the resulting image always have an alpha channel. Is there a way to remove the alpha channel when creating the CGImage?

Comment: I suppose you could create a new [`CGBitmapContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html) which does not have an alpha channel and call [`CGContextDrawImage()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) to draw it there.